# javascript regex: match value within string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this expression to check wether if a key exists in a url :

```
new RegExp('/'+x+'/ig')
```

(removed the irrelevant code)

Thing is, it isn't working. I suppose I have to use delimiters (start and end) to work, since the url has many other things, but not sure how to do it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you put up an example of the url and what you want the output to be?

Comment: Some examples of the URLs you're matching and the keys you're trying to match would make your question clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use [`new Regex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp), you have to pass the flags as a second parameter

```
new RegExp(x, 'ig')
```

Note that you *don't* need the literal delimiters when you create a `RegExp` this way

Answer (score 2):

It kinda looks like you're mixing regexp literals and strings.

One way to write a regexp is like this:

```
var myExp = new RegExp('[a-z]*')
```

It matches any number of letters from a-z, any number of times.
Another way to do the same thing would be like this:

```
var myExp = /[a-z]*/
```

or even

```
var myExp = /[a-z*]/ig
```

where `ig` means "ignore case" and "global".

So, stick to one way of writing it. Don't mix strings and literals.

Edit:

If you want to use the first syntax, but also ignore case and make the match global, pass the string `'ig'` as a second argument to the RegExp-constructor (`new RegExp('[a-z]*', 'ig')`)